# Winston Improper Log Configuration

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have decided to use `winston` for logging in my `node` project. I am developing this application on windows platform but ultimatly it would be on a linux platform.

Here is the code I have used to configure the logger.

```
/* Custom logging module
 * to write appropriate logs into log files as well as console.
 */

var winston = require( 'winston' );

winston.setLevels({
    info: 0,
    error: 1,
    warning: 2,
    audit: 3
});

winston.addColors({
    info: 'blue',
    error: 'red',
    warning: 'yellow',
    audit: 'green'
});

var logger = new ( winston.Logger )({
    levels: {
        info: 0,
        error: 1,
        warning: 2,
        audit: 3
    },

    transports : [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            level: 'info',
            prettyPrint: true,
            colorize: true,
            silent: false,
            timestamp: true
        }),

        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name : 'infoLogger',
            filename : './logs/info-log.log',
            prettyPrint: false,
            level: 'info',
            silent: false,
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true,
            maxsize: 40000,
            maxFiles: 10,
            json: false,
            tailable : true
        }),

        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name : 'errorLogger',
            filename : './logs/error-log.log',
            prettyPrint : false,
            level : 'error',
            silent : false,
            colorize : true,
            timestamp : true,
            maxsize : 40000,
            maxFiles : 10,
            json : false,
            tailable : true
        }),

        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name : 'warningLogger',
            filename : './logs/warning-log.log',
            prettyPrint : false,
            level : 'warning',
            silent : false,
            colorize : true,
            timestamp : true,
            maxsize : 40000,
            maxFiles : 10,
            json : false,
            tailable : true
        }),

        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name : 'auditLog',
            filename : './logs/audit-log.log',
            prettyPrint : false,
            level : 'audit',
            silent : false,
            colorize : true,
            timestamp : true,
            maxsize : 40000,
            maxFiles : 10,
            json : false,
            tailable : true
        })
    ],

    colors: {
        info: 'blue',
        error: 'red',
        warning: 'yellow',
        audit: 'green'
    }
});

module.exports = logger;
```

And I am using fallowing code to log into files.

```
logger.info( 'Winstom Log Info' );
logger.error( 'Winstom Log Error' );
logger.warning( 'Winstom Log Waring' );
logger.audit( 'Winstom Log Audit' );
```

However, there is no colors used in logged messages. And the logged files are not exactly logging their own levels. For example,

`error-log.log` contains fallowing messages.

```
2015-05-23T13:34:32.479Z - error: Winstom Log Error
2015-05-23T13:34:32.480Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:34:32.481Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T13:45:33.433Z - error: Winstom Log Error
2015-05-23T13:45:33.436Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:45:33.436Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T13:56:50.660Z - error: Winstom Log Error
2015-05-23T13:56:50.661Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:56:50.661Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T14:00:04.319Z - error: Winstom Log Error
2015-05-23T14:00:04.319Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T14:00:04.319Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
```

Error log is catching up logs for warning and audit logs as well.
Same is the case for warning logs, it is catching up logs for audit logs as well.

```
2015-05-23T13:34:32.480Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:34:32.481Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T13:45:33.436Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:45:33.436Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T13:56:50.661Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T13:56:50.661Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
2015-05-23T14:00:04.319Z - warning: Winstom Log Waring
2015-05-23T14:00:04.319Z - audit: Winstom Log Audit
```

Right now, only audit log and info log are working as expected. Audit containing only audit logs and info log containing every one of them.

What is it that causing this error ? 
And please also enlighten me on any of the best practices on logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your log levels configured here:

```
levels: {
    info: 0,
    error: 1,
    warning: 2,
    audit: 3
},
```

Winston is behaving exactly as it should. That is, if you have a log file transport set to listen to log level `error` (1), it will capture all logs at that level *and higher*. Maybe you meant to structure your levels like this?

```
levels: {
    info: 0,
    warning: 1,
    error: 2,
    audit: 3
},
```

In this structure, your error log file would only capture `error` and `audit` logs.

As far as your colors not working, are you using `cmd.exe` by any chance? Console colors might not work as they should there. Friends don't let friends use cmd.exe on windows. `cmder` is a much better option, especially for node.js development on windows:

http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/

Comment: So, if I want a log to listen specifically to its own level only, then, they should be configured at same level ? I mean info at 0, and rest at 1 ?

Comment: Well, I tried setting rest at same levels, and it looks like they will listen to all logs configured at 1, is there a way to specify it.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have transports that filter log messages of only a specific log level, and exclude logs at all other levels. Eg. show me `warning` logs, but exclude `info`, `error` and `audit` logs. That's not normally how log levels work, but you can do this by extending one of the existing transports with your own custom one: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports